# Python | xml.etree.ElementTree | Insert tags within a tag

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I'm trying to recreate an XML that has a format similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Data>
    <Source Filename="C:\Data\Test01">
        <Destination Filename="d:\Data\Test01.52829662.file"/>
        <Destination Filename="d:\Data\Test01.54123124.file"/>
    </Source>
</Data>
```

I've used this format to create the "Source" level (tag?):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# Open the xml file 
xml = ET.parse(xml_name)

data = {file:"C:\Data\Test01", ["d:\Data\Test01.52829662.file", "d:\Data\Test01.54123124.file"]}
    
source_tag = [ET.SubElement(xml.getroot(), "Source") for name in data]
destination_tag = [[ET.SubElement(xml.getroot(), "Destination")
                                     for trial in xml[name]] for name in xml.keys()]
```

It instead, appears like this

```
<Data>
    <Source Filename="C:\Data\Test01" />
        <Destination Filename="d:\Data\Test01.52829662.file"/>
        <Destination Filename="d:\Data\Test01.54123124.file"/>
</Data>
```

I'm not sure how to embed the tags correctly

Also, I'm not sure how to recover the header line. Specifically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I figured out is to change the "root" element for the Destination tag. I had been using the incorrect first input (xml.getroot()). Instead, I should've been using the "source_tag":

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# Open the xml file 
xml = ET.parse(xml_name)

data = {file:"C:\Data\Test01", ["d:\Data\Test01.52829662.file", "d:\Data\Test01.54123124.file"]}
    
source_tag = [ET.SubElement(xml.getroot(), "Source") for name in data]
destination_tag = [[source_tab[name], "Destination")
                                     for trial in xml[name]] for name in xml.keys()]
```